# transparently abstract a iostream interface

Tags: c++, iostream

For certain programs, it would be a good idea to have several streams so I can —with the `<<` operator— feed information for debugging purposes, verbose information, etc...

The point here is that any stream can in the end be writing to a file, sending through the network or standard output without the end user having to know about it or make any changes to the way they feed text to the stream.

With this solution implemented, I expect the program while running can switch from streaming to standard output to a file (for example) either on runtime or startup (via command line arguments).

How can this be best accomplished?

Comment: iostreams *are* an abstract interface, that's exactly what they were designed for.

Comment: @user657267 so how do you switch from writing into a file to stdout in runtime and using the `<<` operator on a single symbol in the end code?

Comment: @Alec You can change the underlying buffer of the stream to the buffer of the target stream.

Comment: @templateboy make it an answer and I will pick it if it works.

Comment: @Alec it sounds like you need a function that accepts an arbitrary stream to perform output on rather than modifying the stream at runtime, you should include some code to show what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the internal `std::streambuf` pointer to point the target output stream:

```
std::streambuf* p = std::cerr.rdbuf(nullptr);
o.rdbuf(p);

// Do what you want with the output stream o which now has std::cerr.rdbuf()

// Reset
std::cerr.rdbuf(p);
```

Comment: @Alec `std::ostream o(nullptr);`

Comment: It worked perfectly for all my needs, thanks for the clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anything that has a `<<` operator defined, you could `#define` keywords for them, if you wanted? For example:

```
ofstream myLogFile("/path/to/my/logFile");
#define Info std::cout
#define Err std::cerr
#define Log myLogFile

Info << "Send this message to cout" << std::endl;
Err << "Send this message to cerr" << std::endl;
Log << "Send this message to my logfile at /path/to/my/logFile" << std::endl;
```

I think this is what you're wanting - this can of course be included in a header, provided you place the inclusion before you use them. As always in this case, `#ifndef` style inclusion guards are probably a good idea.

Don't pick words that you'll be tempted to use for something else, of course.

Comment: Your solution works good but in my case I need to be able to switch the “backend” on runtime or at startup. For example make the Info stream output to a file only if specified in the command like, stdout otherwise.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I guess you'd be better with a wrapper class? I started posting that sort of implementation as a second answer, but I couldn't make a minimal example compile very well. A link to some example source code for a larger project is : http://www.openfoam.org/docs/cpp/ - try searching there for terms like "Pout" and "Perr", or "Sout", "Serr". These should give you an idea, but the website is not overwhelmingly easy to navigate.